# Partitioning in Spark while connecting to RDBMS

Tags: apache-spark

Say I have a RDBMS table with 10,000 records which has a column(pk_key) which is a sequence value starting from 1 to 10,000. I am planning to read it via spark.
I am planning to split into 10 partitions.

So in DataFrameReader jdbc method,my columnName will be "pk_key" and numPartitions will be 10.
What should be the lowerBound and upperBound for these ?

PS: My actual Record count is much higher,i just need to  understand how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any natural key? It may be non-unique. It's hard to determine lowerBound and upperBound to Long values, it will be different in different days.

One thing you can do is to run two queries:

```
select min(pk_key) from table;
select max(pk_key) from table;
```

via normal JDBC Connection. The first query will return lowerBound, the second one - upperBound